Why is children not a valid React.ReactNode without wrapping inside Fragment or other element?
Currently learning typescript and could not find an answer.
When I dont wrap children prop inside an element, I get the error:

Type ReactNode is not assignable to type ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> & ReactElement<an<, any>

interface WrapperProps {
  condition: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Wrapper = ({condition, children}: WrapperProps): JSX.Element => {
   return condition ? (
     <App>
      {children} // error
      //<>{children}</> //would not give error
     </App>
   ) : {children}
}

children:
<div>...content</div>

App:
const App = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

Is the reason because I render children inside Wrapper but also inside App?
Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
